# touch -d '20 seconds ago' not working in alpine

Tags: bash, alpine

I'm trying to use

```
touch -d '20 seconds ago' file.txt
```

Which works in Ubuntu, but not in Alpine.
Anybody knows if there's an additional package that does this, or is it not supported by Alpine itself?

EDIT:

```
# touch --help
BusyBox v1.28.4 (2018-12-06 15:13:21 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

Comment: The free-form date parsing is a GNU touch feature, not Busybox touch. What languages does alpine ship with? Perl? (ref https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#touch and https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Alpine Linux, `touch` is indeed symlinked to BusyBox.

For GNU touch, install the GNU [`coreutils`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.11/main/x86_64/coreutils) package, which provides [/bin/touch](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=touch&path=&name=coreutils&branch=v3.11&repo=main&arch=x86_64):

`apk add coreutils`

Answer (score 2):

This will work with busybox's `touch` & `date` without needing to install GNU coreutils:

```sh
touch -d@$(( $(date +%s) - 20 )) file.txt
```

This calculates the date from epoch time, subtracts 20 seconds, and passes that as the desired time for `touch` to use.

I tested this with BusyBox 1.30.1 (via `busybox touch -d@$(( $(busybox date +%s) - 20 )) file.txt`)

Also note that this will work with the GNU versions of those commands as well as almost any implementation of `date` (GNU, BSD, OS X, BusyBox, etc), though [POSIX  `date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) does not specify `%s` and [POSIX `touch`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) does not specify `-d@epoch` (and BSD/OSX doesn't implement it).